# How do I follow a redirect with Test:WWW::Mechanize?

Tags: perl, testing

I have a form, I `submit_form_ok` the form codes to `/process` which returns a redirect to say `/`. How can I follow the redirect to make sure it's doing the right thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WWW::Mechanize` follows redirects automatically for you.  So, unless you want to test that it sent you to `/process` before it sent you to `/`, you shouldn't have to care.  And, really, if  you wind up in the right place with the right page, do you care how you got there?

Comment: must've been some other problem I had then... it didn't appear to be ending up in the right place. I guess I fixed it in between here and there.